# Where to find dragons?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Do dragons live in specific biomes? Are there even multiple types of dragons that live in specific biomes? I have put in a couple of hundred hours, slayed many forgotten beasts, but never encountered a dragon. Most of the time I embark in a biome with a lot of trees from wilderness to terrifying. Also I usually play in worlds that are 100 to 200 years old, since dragons grow to full size in 800 my worlds are relatively new for these creatures.

Comment: Dragons are pretty special. You might have better luck with an adventurer with good gear, civilisation rulers often send you to fight dragons, rocs and other megabeasts.

Comment: However there are reports of players domesticating dragons, even pet dragons lighting up all the booze for some !!FUN!!. Really looking forward to experiment with a dragon.

Answer (score 3):

No, dragons don't have a specific associated biome. As for age, again, I don't think it matters. For a younger world, that just means any dragons you'll encounter will be smaller.

Dragons are just really rare and you've been terribly unlucky. :(

Check out the wiki for more info: http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Dragon

Comment: I might have been lucky :D. I checked all there is about on the DF wiki and other places but there is so little to find about them, perhaps more !!science!! is needed.